How does oxidation state truly track the loss and gain of electrons?
In the book Chemical Principles: The Quest for Insight (7th ed.) by Peter Atkins and Loretta Jones, it's stated that chemists assign an "oxidation number" to each element to keep track of electrons. However, I'm confused about how exactly this works. Isn't oxidation state just an extrapolation based on partial charges acquired by the atom.
How does the oxidation state reliably track the number of electrons lost or gained by an atom? Is it just a coincidence that the change in oxidation state corresponds to the number of electrons transferred, or is there a deeper principle behind this? I'd appreciate any clarification on how oxidation numbers maintain this electron accounting in both simple and more complex compounds.
I've seen the duplicates, but they haven't addressed my questions. Please don't close this question. I really need an answer, and I've been wondering about this for a while. Can you explain how oxidation states track electrons in the following reaction
$\ce{2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O}$

ON/OS is nothing else but very formal electron accounting, based on total charge conservation, leading to the total ON/OS conservation.

How do you imagine this "track the number of electrons lost or gained by an atom?" As Poutnik says ON/OS is nothing else but very formal electron accounting - formal meaning only on paper - it is only tangential to reality, even as far as partial charges are concerned.

Sir can you elaborate please

There are no gained nor lost electrons there. ON is about the thought operation where would valence electrons have ended and what would have been the charge on each atom, if all bonds had been broken and both their valence electrons had remained at the more electronegative atoms of the bond.

This is covered in An introduction to "oxidation state"/"oxidation number". M.A.R.  wrote "So you have to understand that OS does not happen. It doesn't refer to any real-life phenomenon."

@Poutnik so can I understand it like this: ON/OS is a consequence of charge conservation and it give us an approximate idea of electronic configuration around each element, So if ON changes that means the electronic configuration around that element is changed. So we can calculate the number of electrons gained or lost as used in electrochemistry problems

@Logan ON is just a mental construct and does not have direct connections to electronic configuration. It is nothing more than very specific way of Valence electron inventory. But yes, total ON is directly related to electrochemical electron gain  or lose.
